# Java - Load new html page when event occurs

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am using an AJAX request to redirect a user to another page inside my web servlet. 
When the page is redirected, I can see through the log that the method doGet or doPost was load but the PrintWriter does not create the html tag.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
                performTask(request, response);
               log.info("doPost");
    }

private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("TestServlet says hi<br/>");

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + "<html>\n"+"<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"formation.css\">");
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<h3>Simple Html</h3>");
          out.println("</body></html>");
        }
```

I am probably missing something as I this is my first time I actually try to implement a servlet. The message is automatically shown to the user and he does not press any button in order to be redicted. Is this the problem? (Regarding the POST)

Thanks

Comment: Ajax response return this page as string format, if you have set `setContentType` otherwise. Using this string content, 
`var w = window.open();
$(w.document.body).html(response);`